# Camera shift event observation in 2Gis map SDK

Tags: android

I have added maps from 2gis to my project.
Can I know when the user moved the map by gesture and when it happened programmatically via map.camera.move()

watch to MapView.gestureManager but can't find something usefull

Thanks!